Z-index for TimePicker
In my app, I have a pop-up for setting data of events. One of this data is the time. For this I use the DateTimePicker from MUI.
<Popup
                width={600}
                height={600}
                /../
            >
                <div className={"group"}>
                        <div className={"label1"}>Name</div>
                        <div className={"label2"}>
                            <FormControl>
                                <DesktopTimePicker

The problem that I encounter is that the second pop-up from the TimePicker remains hidden behind the first one. I tried changing the z-index to 10000 but this doesn't help. In the browser, the following is shown:
.css-1anqmj6-MuiPopper-root-MuiPickersPopper-root {
    z-index: 1300;
}

.MuiPickersPopper-root {
    z-index: 10000;
}

Does this mean that I can't override the value?
This is my css:
.MuiPickersPopper-root {
    z-index: 10000; !important;
}

.group {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.6em;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.group .label1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
}

.group .label2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 75%;
}


Without more information it's difficult to say. One thing to consider is that z-index is also dependent on the parent element - so you can set it as high as you want, but if the parent container of the second picker has a lower z-index or occurs first in the layout compared to the container of the first picker, it will show underneath

I found the problem after a few hours - the semicolon after the index must be deleted: z-index: 10000 !important;
